# Sails v10 Skipper and UUID

Tags: sails.js

I have a Sails app and am uploading files with the following simple code in the relevant controller:

`upload: function(req,res){
  req.file('files').upload({
    dirname: './uploads/',
    maxBytes: 1000000
    },function (err, uploadedFiles) {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(500, err);
    } else {
      return res.json({
      message: uploadedFiles.length + ' file(s) uploaded successfully!',
      files: uploadedFiles
      });
    }
  });

}`

In the docs it says that "*By default, Skipper decides an "at-rest" filename for your uploaded files (called the fd) by generating a UUID and combining it with the file's original file extension when it was uploaded ("e.g. 24d5f444-38b4-4dc3-b9c3-74cb7fbbc932.jpg").*"

This is not happening. My files are being saved in the './uploads/' folder with their original filenames. Just wondering where I'm going wrong for the UUID filenames to be missing. Or have I just misunderstood the docs?. I'm not getting any console warnings or errors. I really would like to have Skipper handle the unique naming of any files, just for simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the ground is probably shifting under your feet; what you're referring to is a very recent update.  It works for me using the [latest Skipper from Github](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper), but it may not have been published to NPM just yet.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **sgress454** comment:

Skipper is updated in the global sails-packages only 14 hours ago: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/commit/3af77c42a5d8c7687e3d56eeefd9cffdfc24195b

This new packages.json may not be includes in the current npm install of "sails".

To solve this problem you can do:

```
cd yoursails_project/node_modules/sails
npm install skipper --save
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Suppose that these little things are the price one has to pay for using the pre release version. I actually ended up just creating my own simple function to give the uploaded files a unique name.

Comment: My understanding is that it is not necessary to install Skipper though, as it is already ported into Sails as a replacement for bodyParser? It's certainly not in my package.json (I did have to add Skipper-Disk), nor in my app's node-modules, but the upload function from the Skipper docs works fine. Just without the renaming.

Comment: Look at the packages.json in your sails-app. You will find it in yoursails_project/node_modules/sails/packages.json

Comment: Ah right. It all becomes clear. I have Sails installed globally. This must be why it appears to be missing in my 'local' project. Doh!